# Why OBJECT_ID used while checking if a table exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to check if a table in SQL exist or not.

If not it must create one automatically.

Now I researched and found this code:

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTable]') AND type in (N'U'))

BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[YourTable](
....
....
....
) 

END
```

Can anyone explain why it says where `object_id = OBJECT_ID` and what should I put in its place?

Comment: The question does not appear to be asking what OBJECT_ID is, but why it is even used at all in this instance.  Interesting question, because this seems like it would work as well... `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='YourTable')...`

Comment: in sys.objects the schema is a number FK pointing to a schema's system view -- the OBJECT_ID() function will parse the string and get the right objectID (every object has a unique id in sql server) and you can include the schema name in the string you pass to OBJECT_ID(). IMHO - the more declarative way to do it is using the ISO view INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES (which I've given and answer for)

Comment: `IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTable]','U')  IS NOT NULL` is sufficient. The query against `sys.objects` is superfluous.

Comment: @MartinSmith is correct -- and this is probably the most concise way of checking existence in sql server.

Comment: @MartinSmith - what is the purpose of the N preceding the apostrophe? I've seen this with a few other times that these character strings are used and never understood what it did

Comment: @AlexWatts it means the string literal following is an `nvarchar`. For `dbo.YourTable` it won't make any difference but it can in the uncommon case that the table name contains characters that don't exist in the code page of the database's default collation.

Answer (score 94):

I like this syntax:

```
if(object_id(N'[dbo].[YourTable]', 'U') is not null)
...
```

Where object_id takes the 2 char type of object as the second parameter. You can find the list of Object types listed below in the [sys.objects documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx):

- AF = Aggregate function (CLR)
- C = CHECK constraint
- D = DEFAULT (constraint or stand-alone)
- F = FOREIGN KEY constraint
- FN = SQL scalar function
- FS = Assembly (CLR) scalar-function
- FT = Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
- IF = SQL inline table-valued function
- IT = Internal table
- P = SQL Stored Procedure
- PC = Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure
- PG = Plan guide
- PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint
- R = Rule (old-style, stand-alone)
- RF = Replication-filter-procedure
- S = System base table
- SN = Synonym
- SO = Sequence object
- SQ = Service queue
- TA = Assembly (CLR) DML trigger
- TF = SQL table-valued-function
- TR = SQL DML trigger
- TT = Table type
- U = Table (user-defined)
- UQ = UNIQUE constraint
- V = View
- X = Extended stored procedure

Comment: You don't need the enclosing parenthesis but I am nitpicking

Answer (score 9):

The ISO SQL way to check existence of a table level object is the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view

There's nothing *wrong* with looking at sys.objects but.... INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is a bit more declarative -- and it's cross platform (which often doesn't matter at all but meh still nice.)

I think this is probably more readable for a new coder though:

```
DECLARE @tableName SYSNAME = 'tbfoo'
DECLARE @schemaNAme SYSNAME = 'fooSchema'

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('%s exists in schema: %s', 0, 1, @tableName, @schemaName)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('%s DOES NOT EXIST in schema: %s', 0, 1, @tableName, @schemaName)
END
```

Don't worry about the RAISERROR command -- its just a nice way of printing formatted messages.

You can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA view to get a sense of what's in it.

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

As you can see -- you can reference schemas and catalogs by name rather than looking up their ID with OBJECT_ID()

Answer (score 3):

```
object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTable]')
```

`object_id` is the column name in `sys.objects`

`OBJECT_ID` is a function that returns the `ID` for the object you specify, i.e. `YourTable`.

You are comparing the object_id of `YourTable` with the `object_id` column in the `sys.objects` table.  You need to replace `YourTable` with the table name you want to check already exists.

Comment: So must i leave as is like this :

Comment: @user2564223 - just replace `[dbo].[YourTable]' with `[dbo].[THETABLEYOUNEEDTOCHECKEXISTSORNOT]`

Comment: WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Pastel_Companies]') AND type in (N'U'))

Answer (score 1):

`OBJECT_ID()` is a function which returns the Object ID. See the documentation:

> Returns the database object identification number of a schema-scoped
>   object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx

---

By passing it certain parameters (ie. your table details), it will return an ID. You can then compare this with the IDs in the `sys.objects` table to check whether it currently exists.