# There is already an object named 'checks' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table checks
(
    queries int primary key identity(1,1),
    Payee varchar(30),
    Amount decimal(5,2),
    Remarks varchar(50)
);
```

Microsoft SQL Server throws this error

> There is already an object named 'checks' in the database

```
insert into checks (Payee, Amount, Remarks)
values
('Ma Bell', 150, 'Have sons next time'),
('Reading R.R.', 245.34, 'Train to Chi'),
('Ma Bell', 200.32, 'Cellular Phone'),
('Local Utilities', 98, 'Gas'),
('Joes Stale & Dent', 150, 'Groceries'),
('Cash', 25, 'Wild Night Out'),
('Joans Gas', 25.1, 'Gas');
```

SQL Server throws this error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Payee'.

I tried executing the query in Microsoft SQL Server and it displayed the error mentioned above.

I expect the query should run without error

Answer (score 2):

Table you are trying to create already exists. Instead of re-creating it you can add the new column "Payee" like following.

```
ALTER TABLE checks
ADD Payee varchar(30);
```

Once the table is altered, you can execute your insert statements.

If you want to drop the table and re-create it, you can use following DROP command to drop the table.

```
DROP TABLE checks;
```

**Note:** Once you `DROP` the table, all the existing data will be deleted.

So, your final query should look like following.

```
--Create the New column Payee if not exists in the table
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   sys.columns 
  WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Checks]') 
         AND name = 'Payee'
)
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE checks
   ADD Payee varchar(30);
END
--Insert the Data

insert into checks (Payee, Amount, Remarks)
values
('Ma Bell', 150, 'Have sons next time'),
('Reading R.R.', 245.34, 'Train to Chi'),
('Ma Bell', 200.32, 'Cellular Phone'),
('Local Utilities', 98, 'Gas'),
('Joes Stale & Dent', 150, 'Groceries'),
('Cash', 25, 'Wild Night Out'),
('Joans Gas', 25.1, 'Gas');
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, :) sure I will take care of this in future. Will remove now

Answer (score 1):

Try conditionally dropping the `checks` table, if it exist, before running your create statement:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.checks', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.checks;

CREATE TABLE checks (
    queries int primary key identity(1,1),
    Payee varchar(30),
    Amount decimal(5,2),
    Remarks varchar(50)
);

# followed by insert
```

Comment: Sorry I am unable to comprehend your reply as I am a beginner in SQL

Comment: @Kalpana: First 2 lines of the query will check the table exists before you creating it. So that, while you executing your script, it will not throw error if the table is availbale. Check this link for any calrifications. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546814/why-object-id-used-while-checking-if-a-table-exists-or-not`